# How to start Oracle database's listener service after a change in the IP address?

Tags: oracle, windows

I'm using Windows XP as my Oracle database server. Today there was a change in the IP address if the database server.

I want start my database instance's listener again. Windows XP prompst that:

```
OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListenerMZOA_LISTENER service on the local computer started and stopped. Some services stop automatically if they do not have anything to do.
```

(ps:MZOA is the name of my db instance)

I updated `listener.ora` to reflect the new IP.

And my `listener.ora` is:

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ADR_BASE_MZOA_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator

MZOA_LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =CHINA-F781B4F30)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521))
 #caution:192.168.1.100 is my new ip
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_MZOA_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME =mzoa)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
   )
  )
```

Unfortunately when I want start the listener, Windows still shows the above prompt. And I donn't know how to do.

Comment: Is there anything in the listener log? Did you try to stop and start it using LSNRCTL instead? That might also show additional errors on the console

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this it is best to delete the listener using the net configuration tools and recreate it.  Stop the listener service before doing this.  Oracle gets very picky when IP addresses change.

Comment: Umm, no it doesn't, not on Unix systems anyway. That is one of the reasons the listener is a seperate process, so you can fiddle with it without affecting the DB at all, or start another listener, or anything else you want to do.

Comment: Yes I would anticipate it works correctly with Unix.  In windows environments however it doesn't.

Comment: "Net Config assistant" , solution works, Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

Check the installation guide. Install the microsoft local virtual loopback adapter and bind a TCP/IP number to that adapter, then bind the database/listener on that address